# get value of a column mysql with column name as variable

Tags: mysql, transpose

I want to transpose one row of a table.

For example if I have a "Persons" table with "ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Age" as attributes, I want to get transpose of a row in "Persons" table with following two columns:

Column_name, Column_value

I can get the column names of table using:

```
SELECT *
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='databasename'
AND `TABLE_NAME`='tablename';
```

I tried to get values of column names using:

```
select attributes.`COLUMN_NAME`, person.attributes.`COLUMN_NAME` as `Column_Value`
from (select * from Persons where ID=1) as person,
(SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='databasename' and `TABLE_NAME`='tablename');
```

But the second parameter is also giving the column names instead of values.

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: Column names aren't data and it's hard to make them into data. however, the related questions on the right side might give you a hint. There usually is really no good reason to do this on the database side but it's likely more useful to do on the frontend/code-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a stored procedure with prepared statement

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE query longtext;
  SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("(select '",column_name,"' as     col_name,",concat("person.",column_name)," as col_val
    FROM (select * from test.game_action where id=1) as person,(SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test' and `TABLE_NAME`='game_action')as t)")  SEPARATOR ' union ') into query
  FROM (select * from test.game_action where id=1) as person,(SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test' and `TABLE_NAME`='game_action')as t;

 SET @s = query;
 PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

and you can pass the id as parameter if you want

Comment: I tried the same code in phpMyAdmin but i didn't get any error, and it gives the same result that you are looking for @pkgajulapalli

Comment: I was checking in mysql workbench. I'll try once again. @Imanez

Comment: I found the problem. It was the group_concat_max_len limit. It's default value is 1024. After changing it this solution worked. Thank you @Imanez

Comment: You're welcome @pkgajulapalli . Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem.